# Images don't load after htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to redirect all IPs to a specific page except my IP. and I successfully did that, but if that page has some pictures they won't ever load. Tried more than one solution, but nothing works.

How I redirect them using .htacess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (?:^|/)(css|js|img)/(.+)$ /$1/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^22\.22\.22\.22
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/test.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /test.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Images (and CSS and Javascript) don't load, because the first rule causes a rewrite loop. If you just want to serve requests to subfolders `css`, `js` or `img` without modification, you can exit the rule chain by using `-` as the target, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **- (dash)**
>       A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

```
RewriteRule ^(?:css|js|img)/ - [NC,L]
```